# How to pipe two inputs to the same command?

Tags: unix, pipe, stdin

I want to run a command that accepts two arguments that can be either file path or `-` to read the content from stdin.

Example:

```
convert file1.txt file2.txt
cat file1.txt | convert - file2.txt
cat file2.txt | convert file1.txt -
```

All three commands would produce the same result.

Is there a way to pipe in the inputs for both of its arguments?

The reason I ask this is because I want to avoid using the filesystem for running this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html#:%7E:text=Process%20substitution%20feeds%20the%20output,the%20stdin%20of%20another%20process.&text=There%20is%20no%20space%20between,would%20give%20an%20error%20message.&text=Bash%20creates%20a%20pipe%20with,%2D%2DfIn%20and%20fOut%2D%2D.):

`convert <(cat file1.txt) <(cat file2.txt)`

Comment: What's the name of this `<()` operator or where can I find more about it?

Comment: It's process substitution. I've added a link to the answer

Comment: Thank you so much! 